# $B(a, p^n) = \bar{B}(a, p^{n-1})$ in $\mathbb{Q_p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

In an article about $p$-adic numbers I have read that

$B(a, p^n) = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}_p \mid \left\| x - a \right\|_p < p^n \} = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}_p \mid \left\| x - a \right\|_p \leq p^{n-1}\} = \bar{B}(a, p^{n-1})$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and sadly, I don´t understand this. Can someone please give me an explanation ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty in understanding it? Do you for example, know what norm is? Try to give some account if what you tried so that we can identify the source if your problem and address it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\Bbb Q_p$ the only possible nonzero distances between elements are
$p^m$ for $m\in\Bbb Z$. Therefore if $\|x\|_p<p^n$ ($n\in\Bbb Z$)
then $\|x\|_p\le p^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am always glad to obtain help from you. Actually, this was not so difficult to see. Now everything is fine ;).