# In $\mathbb{Q}_p$ a closed ball of radius $p^n$ is the disjoint union of closed balls of radius $p^{n-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

I try to understand why in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ a closed ball of radius $p^n$ is the disjoint union of closed balls of radius $p^{n-1}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ or more precisely,

> $\bar{B}(x, p^n) = \bigsqcup_{i=0}^{p-1} \bar{B}(x_i, p^{n-1})$ for some $x = x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_{p-1}$.

What I know so far is that open (closed) balls in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are also closed (open) and that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the disjoint union of $p$ cosets of $p\mathbb{Z}_p$, i.e. of $p$ balls of radius $\frac{1}{p}$.

Can someone help me further ?

Thanks.

Comment: Let us consider without restriction that $x=0$. As an example (which is typical using a rescaling) we consider $n=0$. So we need to understand the closed ball in $\Bbb Q_p$ of radius one centered in $0$. This is $\Bbb Z_p$. Each element in $\Bbb Z_p$ can be expressed as $0$ or $1$ or ... or $(p-1)$ plus an element in $p\Bbb Z_p$...

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936363/ba-pn-barba-pn-1-in-mathbbq-p).

Comment: In agreement with @dan_fulea, I point out that since you’ve proved it for the special closed ball $\Bbb Z_p$, you have in fact proved it for all closed balls, by scaling (and translating) properly.